# Dúvidas sobre linguagem javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Bom dia!

Pessoal, sou iniciante em **javascript** e tenho algumas dúvidas sobre o trecho abaixo:

```js
var url;
function newUser(){
  $('#dlg').dialog('open').dialog('setTitle','Novo Cliente');
  $('#fm').form('clear');
  url = 'salvar_cadastroclientes.php';
}
function saveUser(){
  $('#fm').form('submit',{
    url: url,
    onSubmit: function(){
      return $(this).form('validate');
    },
    success: function(result){
      var result = eval('('+result+')');
      if (result.success){
        $('#dlg').dialog('close');  // close the dialog
        $('#dg').datagrid('reload'); // reload the user data
      } else {
        $.messager.show({
          title: 'Erro',
          msg: result.msg
        });
      }
    }
  });
}
```

Na função salvar, o código está capturando o `submit` do `form`.

E na segunda linha, o que é esse `url: url`, `onSubmit`...  ?

Comment: É a action do formulário. Para onde vai ao ser dado o submit.

Comment: Esse `.form()` é de algum plugin? nesse caso qual?

Comment: A duvida não é sobre a linguagem e sim sobre o algorítimo.

Comment: exato, a dúvida é sobre o que faz esse URL: URL, onSubmit :[] , success: []

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
**url:** *url,*
```

O primeiro **url** é o nome de um atributo.
No seu caso o objeto .form tem 2 atributos: `**url:** e **onSubmit:**`
o **url:** está recebendo a variável *url,*
Entretanto creio que deve ocorrer um erro, pois no escopo da function saveUser(){...} a variável *url* não foi definida, mas ele foi na

`function newUser(){ ... url = 'salvar_cadastroclientes.php'; }`

Comment: Ivan, muito obrigado!
Outra dúvida, o success também é um atributo?

na linha success: function(result) o result vem de onde? do retorno do onSubmit?

Comment: Não vai ter erro não, porque a variável foi declarar com escopo global lá em cima. A função newUser apenas define ela.